# Python Logging module prints to console even when propagate=False

Tags: python, logging

Im trying to use the logging module to print to file.
IT works fine, my file has my logs but It also shows those logs to my console window, which i dont want to happen.
I tried the following:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('log')

hdlr = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=200000, backupCount=3)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s -- %(levelname)s -- \n%(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr) 
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.propagate = False
```

even tough, it still prints to console.
Any ideas why?

Comment: What log function do you use to log? `logger.log`?

Comment: I use `logger.exception(msg)` or error / info instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely you have a call to `logging.basicConfig()` somewhere, or a call to `logging.info()` or similar (calling a module-level function, rather than a logger method).

The module-level functions are meant for simple usage, and create and add a console handler if  no handlers are assigned to the root logger. So ensure that you have no `logging.debug(...)` style calls and that you're not calling `basicConfig()` or other logging configuration functions which might be changing your logging configuration.

Comment: I have created another version of my class, using basicConfig and indeed, it works now. Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to call basicConfig?

Comment: @Fermi-4 You don't *need* to. It's used to add a handler to the root logger, if it doesn't have any.